# Spring boot acitvemq keep receiver running periodically

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, messaging

I have configured a spring boot application which when run reads messages from the queue and processes them accordingly.
I also have configured the concurrency flag to run multiple such readers.
However in an ideal world i would like the receiver to keep running like a thread and keep checking for any messages.
My question is that whether there is any way i can configure this in spring boot or i have to fallback to using threading mechanism using executor or anything else.
Thanks,
- Vaibhav

Comment: It sounds like you could make use of Spring Framework's message listener container (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-mdp). It'll take care of the threading for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice way from Spring Boot, the concurrency was of course taken case by concurrent attribute e.g.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myqueue", concurrency="2-10")
```

However for the Thread part below was something which is a neat way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJms
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Joining Thread ctrl+c to bring down application");
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```